# Excel VBA Dialog box with custom buttons

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to create a dialog box or message box in excel WITH custom button labels i.e. FIRST and SECOND.  I would like for this box to open up when the file is first opened...and doesn't allow user access to the worksheet until they select either FIRST or SECOND.

I can make a form, but I would rather not add a form since this should be simple...  I remember doing something very similar back in the VB6 days, but that has been sometime.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Modifying Yes/No options in Vba](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25294483/modifying-yes-no-options-in-vba)

Comment: it can be changed. [stackoverflow.com/...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34225068/change-the-language-of-yes-no-buttons-in-vba-dialog/34226049#34226049)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The MsgBox function does not support different names (than the given ones) for the buttons, and neither the InputBox method or function will allow you to change the button names.

You'll have to make a simple form.