# In Excel VBA Is there a way to edit the MsgBox, vbYesNo buttons caption?

Tags: excel, vba

When the following code runs:

```vb
A = MsgBox(Prompt:="Do you wish to play on two courts?", Buttons:=vbYesNo + vbQuestion, Title:="AVAILABLE COURTS")

If A = vbYes Then
    B = MsgBox(Prompt:="Canadian Doubles match on one court and singles match on the other!", Title:="2 COURTS AVAILABLE")
    m = "TERRAINS 5-B"
    o = "TERRAINS 5-B (2)"
    p = "MATCHS"
    CASETR
End If
If A = vbNo Then
    C = MsgBox(Prompt:="O.K. 1 doubles match on available court et 1 player awaiting on the bench!", Title:="ONLY 1 COURT AVAILABLE")
    m = "TERRAINS 5-a"
    o = "TERRAINS 5-a (2)"
    p = "MATCHS Banc"
    CASETR
End If
```

The "Yes" and "No" buttons in the message box read "Oui" and "Non" (French). How can I edit these button captions to read "Yes" and "No" in English?

Comment: Without changing your regional/language settings?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I change the names of buttons on a message box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33607987/how-do-i-change-the-names-of-buttons-on-a-message-box)

Comment: Seems necessary to adapt this link to VBA7 to be helpful in more current versions:-(

Comment: My project [VBA.ModernBox](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.ModernBox) does it the _other way 'round_ (uses the native captions), but it could give some ideas should you decide to design a custom messagebox.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it is the easies to create a custom userform. It provides superior customization options and setting it up will take less time than finding a reasonable solution to the question asked.

Comment: So true, but this a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: Recommend reading [UserForm1.Show?] (https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/) which btw gives an outstanding overview of Userform techniques. C.f. [Destroy a modeless userfrom instance properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47357708/vba-destroy-a-modeless-userform-instance-properly) as for modeless forms.