# Changing the width of the MsgBox window (the length of one line of prompt text)

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to display a message to the user. Unfortunately, the MsgBox function displays too small a width and most messages simply look very unfavorable.
For example, this command

```
MsgBox String(126, "x"), vbInformation
```

displays such a window

[image]

I tried to get a better result using wscript.shell but the code is still like this

```
With CreateObject("wscript.shell")
   .PopUp String(126, "x"), , , vbInformation
End With
```

gives me this effect

[image]

Does anyone know how to display a message in which the line length would not be limited to 63  characters of x (if the icon is displayed at the same time)?

I will only add that I tried it on screens with a resolution of 2560x1440 and 1680x1050. In both cases I achieved the same effect.

Comment: If you have to use a MsgBox (not a UserForm) then you could try re-purposing the code at this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34226049/11318818) so that, instead of changing the text on the buttons, it changes the width of the dialog window, possibly using [SetWindowPos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowpos)?